# maintaining emacs buffer history

Tags: emacs

How do I configure Emacs to keep track of the files visited and then allow me to navigate the chain back and forth? I'm not talking about *mini-buffer* or the cursor positions within the buffer, but rather the files themselves. I hope I got the terminology right of buffer vs file vs window.

ie if I visit

```
foo.c -> dired home -> readme.txt -> buffer-list
```

then by pressing some "back key" 3 times, file foo.c should open in the same (current) buffer I was in. Another way to think of it, is how navigation history works in Firefox - I want to browse files within the buffer like the webpages within a Firefox tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command `previous-buffer` which is bound by default to `C-x <C-left>` and `C-x <left>` (or [nakedly](http://www.emacswiki.org/NaKeD), as I prefer to write them, `C-x C-left` and `C-x left`).

Similarly, to move in the other direction, there is command `next-buffer`, bound by default to  `C-x C-right` and `C-x right`.

---

If you use library [**`misc-cmds.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/misc-cmds.el) then you can remap the keys bound to these vanilla commands to *repeatable* versions `previous-buffer-repeat` and `next-buffer-repeat`.

```
(global-set-key [remap previous-buffer] 'previous-buffer-repeat)
(global-set-key [remap next-buffer]     'next-buffer-repeat)
```

Then you can **just hold down** `right` or `left` after hitting `C-x`, to quickly cycle through the buffers.